# Run "read" bash command within ssh expect script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, stdin, expect

Is there a way to execute a "read" command from a spawned ssh subprocess through expect? When I try the below code, read doesn't recognize end of input through "ENTER" key (it just goes to next line). I tried other "read" options (e.g. limiting number of characters, timeout, etc.) but they do not work. I know there are ways to get user input within Expect script itself but I need the input to be received through a bash command.

```
function foo() {
    expect <<EOF
    set timeout -1
    spawn ssh -t $1
    expect "]"

    send "read x\r"    
    expect "]"

    send "echo $x\r"
    expect "]"

    send "exit\r"
    expect eof
EOF
}
```

Comment: Why using _expect_ and not pure _ssh_ only ?

Comment: First, I second the question from Gilles. Second, **why** do you think you need that input to be received through the bash command? Do you think that's the only way to get it into a shell variable?

Comment: (The reason it's not working, by the way, is that `read` is waiting for input from `expect`, not from the user -- expect doesn't forward user input through to the process it's running unless it's explicitly told to, as with the `interact` command).

Comment: Non-ideal setup requires password to be manually entered, hence the ssh+expect combo. The input must be received through the bash command again because of a setup where we need to run custom bash commands through ssh+expect. Bash command happens to require a "read" in this situation.

How would "interact" command be used to transfer control to the bash commands, and not the user?